# Django 1.8. When we use id field in values and annotate operation in django there is ignore another fields in result sql-query

Tags: python, django, group-by, annotate

I want to update Django from 1.7.11 to 1.11.18. But I found a problem. Django makes different sql-queries for different Django versions. For example.
I have a query:

```
Account.objects
       .values('id', 'name', invoice__payment__payment_gateway')
       .annotate(
         pay_paid=Sum('invoice__payment__amount'),
         pay_refunded=Sum('invoice__payment__amount_refunded')
       )
       .order_by('-name', )
```

sql-query for Django 1.7.11:

```sql
SELECT `member_account`.`id`, 
       `member_account`.`name`, 
       `member_payment`.`payment_gateway`, 
       SUM(`member_payment`.`amount_refunded`) AS `pay_refunded`, 
       SUM(`member_payment`.`amount`) AS `pay_paid` 
FROM `member_account` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_invoice` ON ( `member_account`.`id` = `member_invoice`.`account_id` ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_payment` ON ( `member_invoice`.`id` = `member_payment`.`invoice_id` ) 
GROUP BY `member_account`.`id`, `member_account`.`name`, `member_payment`.`payment_gateway` 
ORDER BY `member_account`.`name` DESC
```

Please pay attention to the `GROUP BY` section. There are 3 fields: **id**, **name**, **payment_gateway**.

But we have following sql-query for Django 1.8.19:

```sql
SELECT `member_account`.`id`, 
       `member_account`.`name`, 
       `member_payment`.`payment_gateway`, 
       SUM(`member_payment`.`amount_refunded`) AS `pay_refunded`, 
       SUM(`member_payment`.`amount`) AS `pay_paid` 
FROM `member_account` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_invoice` ON ( `member_account`.`id` = `member_invoice`.`account_id` ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_payment` ON ( `member_invoice`.`id` = `member_payment`.`invoice_id` ) 
GROUP BY `member_account`.`id` 
ORDER BY `member_account`.`name` DESC
```

And we have only one field in the `GROUP BY` section. Why do we have only one **id** field? It is main question.

BUT when I remove **id** field from `values` section Django 1.8 makes valid sql-query:

```sql
SELECT `member_account`.`name`, 
       `member_payment`.`payment_gateway`, 
       SUM(`member_payment`.`amount_refunded`) AS `pay_refunded`, 
       SUM(`member_payment`.`amount`) AS `pay_paid` 
FROM `member_account` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_invoice` ON ( `member_account`.`id` = `member_invoice`.`account_id` ) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_payment` ON ( `member_invoice`.`id` = `member_payment`.`invoice_id` ) 
GROUP BY `member_account`.`name`, `member_payment`.`payment_gateway` 
ORDER BY `member_account`.`name` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent Django versions seem to omit redundant fields from the `group by` clause. If you group by a unique field in a table, there is no point in grouping by any further fields from that table. This definitely explains the omission of `member_account.name`, which is redundant if you have the unique `member_account.id` in the query.

The same might be true of `payment_gateway` *if* you have constraints to the effect that every account shall only have one `payment_gateway`. If accounts can have several payment gateways, then I see no immediate explanation for why Django considers the field redundant for `group_by` purposes.

If you show the definitions of the relevant models, we may be able to tell you more.